# Shaky & Choppy CSS Scale Transform on Background Image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform, scale

I have a background image that has a parent div with a transform: scale with an animation applied to it, giving the effect of the background image zooming in slowly when you land on the page.

It renders perfect accross the board except in ie 10/11. I've got all the proper pre-fixes added in, but still get a really shaky and choppy animation in ie.

I've researched and applied acceleration hacks, but nothing gives.

Does anyone have a fix or has seen something along these lines?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, but just with an image, not background image, and for me the solution was to give `transform: rotate(0.01deg);` to the parent of the scaled element.

Of course you will have a minimal rotation, so it depends on your css codes, if this wouldn't cause another problem.

Comment: This worked great for me and really saved the UX for a project that heavily relied on a smooth scaling effect in lots of places. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because it's an image and there are not "in between" pixel renderings when doing transforms. I'm not sure there's a solution to this problem right now.

You could try doing it in canvas, though I know that's usually not the desired route to go.